# Can a JUnit test resolve from a object returning a Assertion?

Tags: java, junit, assert

Can a JUnit test resolve from a object returning a Assertion?

For example, if I have a test that looks like this, would this work?

```
@Test
public void testCase1() {
    TestObject to = new TestObject();
    to.login();
    to.runTest();
    // then assert success
    to.verifyTest();

}

public Class TestObject() {
  ....
  public Assert verifyTest() {
    return assertTrue("Test result not found.", this.validateTestResult() );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this type of testing on projects where developers do BDD style tests. This has the benefit that the code is **very** readable, but the drawback that as a unit test is a too abstract, so it's not trivial to understand what a class or method does.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't use some sort of partial mock and/or powermock framework to check on an internal state?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. The type of assertTrue is void, not Assert.

Comment: What I am really wondering here, is "does anyone use this kind of design pattern for web black box tests" or is this a misunderstanding of JUnit on my part?

Answer (score 1):

Most Assert calls throw an `AssertionError` if they fail, so the code wouldn't look exactly the way you put it, but your code could be adjusted slightly and compile/run. Because they are implemented as exceptions, you can call Assert methods from anywhere, including any helper classes you set up to help run your tests easier, as far deep in the stack as you'd like.

**EDIT**: I do very much recommend setting up helper classes if you need to make a similar set of assertions against many objects. I misunderstood and thought your `TestObject` was your system under test; the rest applies to that situation instead.

==

There's nothing to prevent you from calling `Assert` methods from within the class under test, but part of the intention for JUnit is to have clean test classes that are separate from your code classes. That way, the tests can evolve separately and often do not even need to change unless your class's interface changes. In my code, I put them in the same package in a separate "source folder", so you have:

- src/com/mypackage/project1/database/DatabaseAccessor.java
- testsrc/com/mypackage/project1/database/DatabaseAccessorTest.java
- testsrc/com/mypackage/project1/database/DatabaseAccessorSystemTest.java

One of the reasons to separate things this way is to ensure that no testing code is ever run in production; if the `verifyTest` method is in the same class, there's nothing to stop you from calling it within your class--or worse, from other classes calling it from elsewhere in your codebase. You also avoid depending on junit.jar from production code.

If you are looking to make assertions in production code to avoid inconsistent state or illegal arguments, that's a different matter, and one for which you should avoid JUnit's `Assert` class--or, for that matter, `assert` statements (which are compiled out based on arguments to `javac`). Instead, prefer a library like Guava's [`Preconditions`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html).

Comment: One way to keep the test code out of the production code is to make a subclass of the class under test. In the subclass you can declare methods such as runTest and verifyTest.  Of course this assumes that the protected interface is sufficient for testing.  Another trick is to put the test class in the same package as the class under test. This gives you access to the package-level interface.

Comment: @Theodore I dislike inheritance for testing, as it seems to abuse inheritance, but (as in the paths in the answer) like putting things in the same package for exactly the reason you noted. This is particularly effective with an annotation like [`@VisibleForTesting`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html).

Comment: Either approach lets you test "protected" methods in Java. For other languages, subclassing is likely to be the best way to test protected methods.